# How to enable debug info in ant4eclipse build using buildJdtProject?

Tags: java, debugging, ant4eclipse

I have tried setting different properties and attributes (debug="true"), but it didn't work.

This is from our build.xml (just showing the parts relating to the build step):

```
<!-- Environment holen -->
<property environment="env" />

<!-- Target: all -->
<target name="all" depends="build, test, export">
</target>

<!-- Target: build -->
<target name="build">
    <ant4eclipse:executeProjectSet workspaceDirectory="${env.WORKSPACE}" teamprojectset="${env.WORKSPACE}\${env.JOB_NAME}\projectSet.psf">
        <ant4eclipse:forEachProject filter="(executeProjectSet.org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature=*)">
            <buildJdtProject workspaceDirectory="${env.WORKSPACE}" projectName="${executeProjectSet.project.name}" targetLevel="1.6" />
        </ant4eclipse:forEachProject>

    </ant4eclipse:executeProjectSet>
</target>
```

**Detailed description:**
An internal project consists of a large number of classes and some applications, all written in Java.Everything runs just fine when started from within Eclipse.

After each commit to our SVN repository, the project is built using ant4eclipse on our Hudson installation and if tests pass, a zip is automatically created and copied to a file server to be used by simply unpacking and starting the supplied startup batch script.

Now last week a colleague informed me that the version from the file server doesn't work for him. I checked and am able to reproduce the problem - loading data from a database doesn't  work. No exception is shown in the log/console and I have no idea what goes wrong. Everything works when started from within eclipse (same vmargs, same JVM etc.).

When trying to connect the debugger, it seems like no debug info is present ("line numbers missing" etc.). So I now need to find out how to convince ant4eclipse to include debug infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found out how to do this myself: I added a default compiler options file like this (attribute `defaultCompilerOptionsFile`):

```
<!-- Target: build -->
<target name="build">
    <ant4eclipse:executeProjectSet workspaceDirectory="${env.WORKSPACE}" teamprojectset="${env.WORKSPACE}\${env.JOB_NAME}\projectSet.psf">
        <ant4eclipse:forEachProject filter="(executeProjectSet.org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature=*)">
            <buildJdtProject 
                workspaceDirectory="${env.WORKSPACE}" 
                projectName="${executeProjectSet.project.name}" 
                targetLevel="1.6" 
                defaultCompilerOptionsFile="compilerOptions.prefs"/>
        </ant4eclipse:forEachProject>

    </ant4eclipse:executeProjectSet>
</target>
```

compiler options file is just a copy of `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` inside the workspace. Make sure to set the desired options inside the file:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
```

I haven't tested if it works if you create a compiler options file that just contains the 3 lines above.